# Linear Algebra - Self Adjoint - not sure where to begin

Tags: linear-algebra

Prove that a normal operator with real eigenvalues is self adjoint.

I don't even know where to begin!

Comment: Do you know the "spectral theorem" for normal operators?

Comment: Start by looking up the definitions for operator, normal operator, eigenvalue, and self-adjoint, if you don't know them.

Comment: Spectral Theorem: let T be a linear operator on a complex inner product space V. Then V has an orthonormal basis  consisting of eigenvectors for T if T is normal

Comment: So you are in finite dimension, aren't you? Otherwise, the elements of the spectrum are not always eigenvalues...

Answer (score 0):

Hint: By the spectral theorem, you can write a normal operator $T$ as $T = QDQ^{\ast}$, where $Q$ is unitary (e.g. $Q^{\ast} = Q^{-1}$) and $D$ is diagonal. So what happens if the eigenvalues are real? Compare $T$ and $T^{\ast}$.